# Multi-line flexbox, container width is only one column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using multiple line flexbox with `flex-direction: column;`. And flex container is removed from normal flow (for example with `position: absolute;`)

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 110px;
  background: yellow;
  border: solid 1px black; 
}

.item{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;

  border: solid 1px red; 
  margin: 1px; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>

</div>
```

https://codepen.io/SakerONE/pen/zJxXXN

How to make container width to grow with the number of columns? Now the width of the container is only one column (50px).

Comment: Did you know that you can write embedded css and html inside stack overflow?

Comment: @dwjohnston, edited

Comment: I made some edits to the css to make the issue a little clearer.

Comment: grid workaround https://codepen.io/SakerONE/pen/oPXboZ

Answer (score 0):

Do you not just want to use `flex-direction:row`?. You can limit the number of items per row with the use of `flex-basis` on each item.

`flex-basis:33%` on each item will limit to 3 items per row.

---

Alternatively, use `height:auto` on `.container`.

Comment: No. He's clearly writing things in columns.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Didn't understand how height auto will help, fixed height is needed to make multiple columns